# How do I display multiple Prometheus server names in a Grafana table?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql, prometheus-node-exporter

I have multiple Prometheus data sources that I want to display in 1 table. I need them to display like the following:
[image]

Another way of phrasing it would be how do I get the name of a data source to display in each row of the table. Could this be done with template variables or label functions?

Comment: `sum by (data_source)`?

Comment: well, you don't need to get the name of the data source from a function or a metric if this is what you want. You can use mixed sources and multiple[e queries on grafana panel. then on each panel you write a `Legend` w.r.t. the data source that you are collecting the metrics.

Answer (score 1):

Use the "Mixed" data source to aggregate multiple data sources in one panel. From the [docs](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/):

> Mixed - Select this to query multiple data sources in the same panel. When this data source is selected, Grafana allows you to select a data source for every new query that you add.
> The first query will use the data source that was selected before you selected Mixed.
> You cannot change an existing query to use the Mixed Data Source.

Use the "Merge" transformation to combine the data into one data frame.

To achieve exactly what you are looking for here, the easiest way will be to add another label to your metrics on the Prometheus side, presumably named `data_source` or something similar. You can then include the new label in the table headers.

You can do this with [`relabel_configs`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config) in your `prometheus.yml`. For example, with a scrape job for something like the `node_exporter` (which I assume you are using for resource utilization information), try this:

```
  - job_name: 'node_exporter'
    metrics_path: /metrics
    static_configs:
    - targets:
      - prometheus.hostname:9000
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__address__]
        target_label: data_source
        replacement: server1
```

I don't know exactly what your setup is like, but some adaptation of these configuration options should suit your needs.